# Proving the triangle inequality in svm kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality

I was studying about norms and svm(support vector machine) kernels used to define a new measure of distance. In order to ensure that the radial basis function's satisfy the triangle inequality, I need to show the following inequalities:-

If $a,b,c>0$ and $c \leqslant a+b$, the following should hold:-

$$e^{-kc}\leqslant e^{-ka}+e^{-kb}$$
$$e^{-kc^2}\leqslant e^{-ka^2}+e^{-kb^2}$$
for any postive k. Does anyone has a proof of this or a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=3$ $b=2$ and $c=1$.

Thus, for any positive $k$ we need:
$$e^{-3k}+e^{-2k}\geq e^{-k}$$ or
$$1+e^{k}\geq e^{2k},$$ which is wrong for $k=1$.

Comment: does this mean that the svm kernel doesn't really generalize distance as the triangle inequality doesn't hold?